# WP7 - Unable to databind to the same object from two pages

Tags: windows-phone-7, data-binding

1. Page1 creates and databinds to a new instance of Foo (call it theFoo)
2. theFoo.Name is set via textbox from Page1
3. theFoo is saved to a globally accessible data structure (list of Foos, whatever)
4. navigate from Page1 to Page2
5. Page2 databinds to the global list of Foos, to display all Foo instances

When I do this, I can verify that the Foo instance is added to the global list. But Page2 never shows any Foos.

If I manually add Foos to the global list (in code instead of from Page1), then navigate to Page2 without ever navigating to Page1 at all, I see Foos displayed in Page2.

What's the issue here?

Update:

Here's some relevant code...

**Item.cs (Data and global storage structure)**

```
public class Item
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

internal static class ItemRepos
{
    private static List<Item> _items = new List<Item>();

    public static Item New()
    {
        return new Item();
    }

    public static int Count
    {
        get { return _items.Count; }
    }

    public static IEnumerable<Item> GetAll()
    {
        return _items;
    }

    public static Item Get( string name )
    {
        return _items.SingleOrDefault( item => item.Name == name );
    }

    public static void Save( Item item )
    {
        if ( _items.Contains( item ) == false )
        {
            _items.Add( item );
        }
    }

    public static void Remove( Item item )
    {
        _items.Remove( item );
    }
}
```

**Relevant Page1.xaml fragment**

```
<TextBlock Text="Name:"
           Grid.Row="0"
           Grid.Column="0"
           HorizontalAlignment="Right"
           VerticalAlignment="Center"
           Margin="5" />

<TextBox x:Name="txtName"
         Grid.Row="0"
         Grid.Column="1"
         HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
         VerticalAlignment="Center"
         Text="{Binding Name}" />
```

**Page1.xaml.cs**

```
public partial class ItemDetail : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    public ItemDetail()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnNavigatedTo( NavigationEventArgs e )
    {
        base.OnNavigatedTo( e );

        this.DataContext = ItemRepos.New();
    }

    private void Nav( object sender, EventArgs e )
    {
        NavigationService.Navigate( new Uri( "/Page2.xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute ) );
    }

    private void Save( object sender, EventArgs e )
    {
        ItemRepos.Save( (Item) this.DataContext );
    }
}
```

**Relevant Page2.xaml fragment**

```
<controls:PivotItem Header="A-Z">
    <ListBox x:Name="listAZ"
             ItemsSource="{Binding}">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
</controls:PivotItem>
```

**Page2.xaml.cs**

```
public partial class ViewItems : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    public ViewItems()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnNavigatedTo( NavigationEventArgs e )
    {
        base.OnNavigatedTo( e );

        this.DataContext = ItemRepos.GetAll();
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the type of your global data structure? And exactly how do you add theFoo inside?

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing any of your code, its hard to know exactly what is going on, but I'll try guessing. If you add some code to your question, I can be more helpful. Here is a list of possible problems.

- The list of Foos isn't actually static (globally accessible to both pages) and they are referencing different lists.
- You Page1 isn't successfully updating the list of Foos.
- If the list of Foos is an `ObservableCollection`, somewhere you are instatiating it more than once.
- If the list of Foos isn't an `ObservableCollection`, you aren't setting up the data binding correctly between the two pages.

**Update:**
Try using the following instead of `_items` in Item.cs.

```
public static ObservableCollection<Item> Items = new ObservableCollection<Item>();
```

Then, change the `DataContext` of page 2 to use the collection directly:

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo( NavigationEventArgs e )
{
    base.OnNavigatedTo( e );

    this.DataContext = ItemRepos.Items;
}
```

Comment: It's a List<Item>, as defined in the code. I have the same issue if I use an ObservableCollection<Item>.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see that line before. Try making the above change and let me know if that fixes it.

Comment: Nope, doesn't work. I had tried that previously (though I tried again). Something strange I've observed is that if I set a breakpoint in Page2 and examine the contents of the items list (or ObservableCollection<>) in the debugger, I see the added item but it's .Name property value yields a "unable to evaluate expression" error, which seems odd. If I manually construct items and add them to the list in code (instead of in Page1), I don't see this behavior in the debugger. This leads me to believe that Page1 databinding is still affecting the Item instance when trying to display it on Page2.

Comment: Progress... if I change the binding markup in Page1.xaml to use TwoWay binding, then Page2 properly displays items added from Page1. I don't yet understand why the default (OneWay) wouldn't simply fail to propagate changes from the target (TextBox) to the source (Item.Name property). Instead it seems to make the .Name property value throw an error when requested from Page2. I'm clearly still missing something simple here.

Comment: If the binding is `OneWay` on Page1, then the name property will always be null since you are not setting it in code. Because of this, the binding within the `DataTemplate` on Page2 will fail, but there should be an error because bindings fail quietly. What is the error you are getting?